# Javascript - document.createEvent not supported by object

Tags: javascript, events, automation, click

I'm working on an automation project where I am attempting to click a button on a website. I have managed to identify the element but when I attempt to use document.createEvent it tells me that the object doesn't support it. Any ideas?

```js
function categoryClick() {
  var events = ["mousemove", "mouseover", "focus", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"];
  var combobox = document.getElementById("category");
  var a = combobox.childNodes;
  var target = a[0].childNodes[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var eventObject = document.createEvent("Event");
    eventObject.initEvent(events[i], true, false);

    target.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: [`createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) has been deprecated for a while, use [event constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createEvent` is depreciated

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

It has been replaced with `Event()`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

So for your code, this should work as a refactor:

```
function categoryClick() {
  var events = ["mousemove", "mouseover", "focus", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"];
  var combobox = document.getElementById("category");
  var a = combobox.childNodes;
  var target = a[0].childNodes[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var eventObject = new Event(events[i], {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});

    target.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
  }
}
```